# How to prevent a file show up for a second when emacsclient starts?

Tags: buffers, emacsclient

I am using `emacs-daemon`. When every I re-start my daemon and do `C-x C-b` my `Buffer List` seems always full.

Later, when I start my `emacsclient` for a seconds(like a fast flash) it shows a file that located on the top of my `Buffer List` and opens the file I want to open. This is little annoying to face with all the time.

Example:

- I type `emacsclient -t file_a.py`.
- For a second or less, buffer called `file_b.py` opens (my lastly opened file).
- Than `file_a.py` get opens.

### [image]

This always repeats itself even I clean my buffer list doing following and open a new file (since buffer list now contains more than one file):

[Link:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14151947/2402577)

> Edit: There's also the boring old buffer menu you get with `C-x C-b`.
>   In this menu, you can hold d until it marks each buffer for deletion,
>   then press x to commit.

Even after doing this after that `IBuffer` shows up since it is the latest opened buffer.

**[Q]** Is it possible to prevent 1 second file show up when I start `emacsclient`? If possible I always want to keep my `Buffer List` empty, but not sure would it be a good idea, or some how keep a empty file at the top of the buffer list since it will show a blank frame.

This also occurs when I using `emacs -nw` where `scratch*` buffer or latest opened buffer shows up for as seconds as well.

Comment: I've reverted your recent edit because you changed the question to be completely different. Closing old buffers, and changing what order things are displayed when you run emacsclient, are completely different problems. Please do not edit questions in a way that invalidates existing answers.

Comment: Sorry, overall: I just want to ignore show up of a buffer different buffer when I open a file even for a few ms. I think when I open a new file it should be on first order on the buffer list. I think since answer is correct there is no way to do it since it is not available in emacs.

Comment: It occurs to me that you may be misunderstanding something. The `Buffer List` is the list of files that _are currently open_, not some kind of “recent files you might want to reopen”. They'll only go away if you close the files (or restart Emacs, if you aren't using a session saving mechanism). Closing a window has no effect on open files. A file is still open even if it isn't currently visible.

Comment: I am having trouble to explain what is the issue in my casel. `Buffer List` could be remain as it is, as keeping the recent files, I don't want it to go away. I just don't want buffer to pop up for 1 second ,  I capture the screen as what happens ( https://drive.google.com/file/d/11HvZ96b4XmYTETEZ0tLYHkg_hVC8oJC6/view?usp=sharing ).

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of using emacs in daemon mode is to access the set of buffers you have opened since emacs started.

The behaviour you are requesting is available by NOT running emacs in daemon mode, but just opening a new emacs session for each file.

Comment: I face with same issue when I open a new emacs session using `emacs -nw` for each file